# Error sending data to APM even after successful connectivity

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

Able to establish APM connection

```
2021-03-09 17:45:05,741 [Attach Listener] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - VM Arguments: [-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1, -Xmx6g, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=IN, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
2021-03-09 17:45:08,192 [Attach Listener] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.ElasticApmTracer - Tracer switched to RUNNING state
2021-03-09 17:45:08,734 [elastic-apm-server-healthcheck] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerHealthChecker - Elastic APM server is available: {  "build_date": "2021-02-15T12:37:48Z",  "build_sha": "e77061bb3aaedae5ae8dd0ca193eb662513aedde",  "version": "7.11.0"}
```

But post connection, it still throws this error. What could be wrong here, appreciate any inputs on this

```
2021-03-09 17:45:53,484 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Backing off for 0 seconds (+/-10%)
2021-03-09 17:45:53,489 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error sending data to APM server: Read timed out, response code is -1
2021-03-09 17:45:53,489 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - null
2021-03-09 17:46:08,890 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Backing off for 1 seconds (+/-10%)
2021-03-09 17:46:09,922 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error sending data to APM server: Read timed out, response code is -1
2021-03-09 17:46:09,922 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - null
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Same error on 7.17.1 only affecting java applications

Answer (score 0):

Check your kibana.yml file URLs, when I setup APM I my machine some of my URLs (elasticsearch.hosts, xpack.fleet.outputs) were defaulted to my current IP address (instead of localhost), which changed after a reboot.